# Angular - bind label and text value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I want to bind `label.id` and the text entered by user to Detail object. I want to dynamically store the label and the entered text. I do not know how I can bind the two values to an object. I know ng-model is used to bind the entered text, but I want to save the label.id corresponding to the entered text.
If its easier, I  am okay changing datatype of Detail to map instead of array?

```
<div class="mySettings"    
   ng-show="Id !== undefined">    
   <section ng-repeat="label in LabelMap[Id].labels">    
       <label for="{{label.id}}"    
           class="input-field-label">{{label.value}}</label>
        <input id="{{label.id}}"    
        ng-model="...." required />   <!-- add binding here such that myvalue.details.name =  label.id and myvalue.details.value has value text entered-->      
    </section>
<div>
```

**MyModel.js**

```
export interface MyValue {
     details: Detail[];
}

export interface Detail {
        name: string;
        value: string;
    }
```

Comment: Angularjs or angular?

Comment: `<input ng-init='myvalue.details.name=label.id' id="{{label.id}}" ng-model="myvalue.details.value" required />`

Comment: @Ramesh Angularjs

Comment: @Slava, there is a for loop and there could be multiple labels. How can I maintain index here? I'll have to do something like: myvalue.details[i].name?

Comment: @david, may be `myvalue.details[$index].name`?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Thanks. That was helpful.